# Slave: ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: windows-7, ssh, cygwin, port-forwarding, hadoop

i have done with single node cluster on two different machine,I have made one as master(192.168.1.1) and other m/c as slave(192.168.1.2), I am successfully able to ping between two machine,I have made the following changes to get into 2 node cluster Update :-

/etc/hosts on both machines hosts.allow

```
All :  Ashish-PC 192.168.1.1 : allow
All  : slave 192.168.1.2 : allow
```

master file with

```
Ashish-PC
```

client file with

```
Ashish-PC 
slave
```

I am getting an error while copying local host public key to remote host(slave): **port 22**

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@slave
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any    that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out
```

while copying from master node key:-

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@slave
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out
```

i have used cygwin and ssh is working fine on both the PC and I went through some suggestion to change the port number 22(because of ISP problem) but i dont want do that just [because](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/03/12/why-putting-ssh-on-another-port-than-22-is-bad-idea/). thanks in advance for your help and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just allow to communicate through **Windows Firewall** by adding sshd in home as well as public...

[image]

and it successfully worked for me
hope it will save your time and please remember that your sshd service are running on both the PC while communication.

Answer (score 0):

**if you are facing this problem in windows 7 follow these steps to open port for ssh**

Go to windows firewall of security section in control panel

Exceptions->add port

Give port name as ssh and number as 22.

Select option TCP

Click on Ok

This will help you open ssh from cygwin

For local application development like hadoop on windows please

please change the scope "localhost /ip address " in the custom list