# windows ssh localhost: connection refused

Tags: windows, ssh, localhost

I want to try ssh myself (windows) so I open cmd and type: `ssh 127.0.0.1`. But I got this error: `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused`.

I tried to use Putty but I got the same error.

(I even don't know why I can use `ssh` in Windows...)

Beside, I have read a similar question here:
[Slave: ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out](https://superuser.com/questions/643688/slave-ssh-connect-to-host-slave-port-22-connection-timed-out)

But I can't find a program or feature names `sshd` in my computer.

How can I ssh localhost in Windows?

Comment: You shouldn't really need to ssh localhost; just open a command prompt and you've got the same thing (in Windows, press Windows key+R and type `cmd` to open the built-in command prompt)

Comment: @oxguy3  yeah. I understand. I need that because I am coding a cpp project in windows, which needs to remote control another pc to execute another cpp program. Also, I need to be able to remote control the localhost so that I could use all kinds of ip to test or to use my project.

Comment: If you really want to have a remote shell on Windows, check out Powershell Remoting.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/23/an-introduction-to-powershell-remoting-part-one.aspx

Comment: A hint as you try to get this working: I wouldn't expect this SSH to work if "netstat -na" is not showing a LISTENING connection on TCP port 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft does not currently provide SSH server software for its Windows operating system. However, if you haven't already installed SSH server software on your Windows system, there are quite a few commercial SSH server packages available for Windows and there is also free SSH server software. Some companies that provide commercial versions will allow you to use their software for free for noncommercial use. Some free versions that I've used:

[Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-download) - free for personal use

[Copssh](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/Copssh501/) - [the name is from "Cygwin" + "OpenSSH"](https://www.itefix.net/content/why-it-called-copssh)

[freeSSHd](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/network/ssh/freeSSHd/)

[OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) - the software hasn't been updated since, 2004. I found it worked well under Windows XP, but I experienced problems with it on later operating systems and wouldn't recommend it.

[PowerShell SSH Server for Windows](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/PSSrvr6/) - the Personal Edition is free; it limits you to one SSH connection to the server at a time.

[SilverSHield](http://www.extenua.com/silver-shield.html) - [free for personal use version limited to one concurrent SSH connection](http://www.extenua.com/SilverShieldpricing.jpg)

If you've got Cygwin installed already, [you can install OpenSSH server software for Cygwin](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/).

Microsoft has, apparently, "seen the light" and has announced that it intends to provide SSH server software for its Windows operating systems, e.g., see the June 2, 2015 Ars Technica article [Microsoft bringing SSH to Windows and PowerShell](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/06/microsoft-bringing-ssh-to-windows-and-powershell/).

Answer (score 6):

Update to this answer: you can now install OpenSSH Server using the Windows PowerShell. Here's a [link to the instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse).

Comment: Yes, this question could do with an up-to-date answer now.. but your link seems to give me a 404?

Comment: Thx - I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not by default have a SSH Server installed or running.  Did you try to install one? It would be a 3rd party application.  Also windows does not provide a ssh client.  Again this would be a 3rd party application that would need to be installed.

It is quite unusual to install an SSH Server onto Windows.

Comment: alright. I may have installed something before. I forgot. OK, let me try to install sshd service tomorrow.

Comment: I need that because I am coding a cpp project in windows, which needs to remote control another pc to execute another cpp program. Also, I need to be able to remote control the localhost so that I could use all kinds of ip to test or to use my project. Anyway, this is what my boss expect. I have to find a way to remote control a windows from a windows...